# Vertica and PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, vertica

For the last two days, I've been struggling with a very strange bug while I'm connecting with Vertica using PDO. You see, the following script works:

```
$c = new PDO("odbc:Driver=Vertica;Server=x.x.x.x;Port=5433;Database=db;", "MyUser", "MyPassword");
$c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
$stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = 88");
$stmt->execute();
```

After that, I loop through the results and display them no problem. This basically means my connection is correct otherwise I wouldn't get anything out of the database. On the other hand, the following makes the Apache server reset the connection completely (when run in Windows, I get a message that Apache crashed):

```
$c = new PDO("odbc:Driver=Vertica;Server=x.x.x.x;Port=5433;Database=db;", "MyUser", "MyPassword");
$c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
//$c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

try
{
    $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = :cl");
    $stmt->bindValue(":cl", 88);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $res['noClient'] . "<br>";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem is present both in Linux and Windows and I'm using Vertica version 7.0.2-1 along with the corresponding ODBC driver. The problem was also present in Vertica 6.1. Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried to set PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to both true and false without any change.

EDIT: This being a test script, I didn't bother with any error handling. Also, given that the server actually crashes, I doubt it would change anything.

EDIT: Updated the code above to include some basic error handling. Apologies to Kermit for sounding condescending in my earlier comment. Anyway, even with this addition to my code, I still didn't get any message, the server would just silently crash and I'd get a "Connection reset" page. Upon seeing this, I tried querying different tables in my database and on one, instead of a crash, I got the following:

*SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 50310 [Vertica][Support] (50310) Unrecognized ICU conversion error. (SQLExecute[50310] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)*

EDIT: Went to my ODBC DSN, clicked Configure, went on the Server Setting tab and found that the locale was set to: en_US@collation=binary (which is the default for Vertica, I believe). Should I check somewhere else?

EDIT: I was curious to see what the bindValue() was doing to my query and so opened the vertica.log file. Here's what I saw:

```
2014-10-02 11:38:42.100 Init Session:0x5ef3030 [Session] <INFO> [Query] TX:0(vertica-1756:0xbc42) set session autocommit to on
2014-10-02 11:38:42.104 Init Session:0x5ef3030 [Session] <INFO> [PQuery] TX:0(vertica-1756:0xbc42) SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = ?
2014-10-02 11:38:42.105 Init Session:0x5ef3030-a00000000aac68 [Txn] <INFO> Begin Txn: a00000000aac68 'SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = ?'
2014-10-02 11:38:42.915 Init Session:0x5ef3030-a00000000aac68 <LOG> @v_flexgroup_node0001: 08006/2895: Could not receive data from client: No such file or directory
2014-10-02 11:38:42.915 Init Session:0x5ef3030-a00000000aac68 <LOG> @v_flexgroup_node0001: 08006/5167: Unexpected EOF on client connection
2014-10-02 11:38:42.915 Init Session:0x5ef3030-a00000000aac68 <LOG> @v_flexgroup_node0001: 00000/4719: Session vertica-1756:0xbc42 ended; closing connection (connCnt 2)
2014-10-02 11:38:42.916 Init Session:0x5ef3030-a00000000aac68 [Txn] <INFO> Rollback Txn: a00000000aac68 'SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = ?'
```

Apparently, it seems PDO is replacing the placeholders by question marks in the final query. Not all that unexpected, but for some reason, the actual value of the parameter seems to get lost along the way.

EDIT: Following a suggestion, I tried:

```
$stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM myClients WHERE ClientNum = :cl");
$stmt->execute(array(":cl" => 88));
```

But the problem remains the same.

Comment: Try inverting your current setting for `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`. If it is currently `true`, set it `false` and the reverse. I suspect you are not using emulated prepares now, but it might help to do so since PDO/PHP would handle all the parameter binding and substitution before sending to the RDBMS.  (I have no experience with vertica)

Comment: Documented here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: Where is your error handling?

Comment: Just because you didn't *"bother with any error handling"* doesn't mean we're going to guess what's wrong.

Comment: We tried to use pdo once with Vertica. Then we decided to never do it again and use python instead. I do not remember the issues we had, but we never managed to resolve them.

Comment: @Osuwariboy Is your locale set in your ODBC DSN?

Comment: could the issue be related to the use of bindValue() ? Have you tried `->execute(array(':cl'))` while removing the `bindValue()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so after going halfway crazy trying to figure out what was wrong with PDO, I discovered that using PHP odbc module directly worked.

Since all my modules are actually written using PDO and rewriting them was not an option, I ended up writing the following wrapper classes:

```
class PDOVertica
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password)
    {
        $this->conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
    }

    public function prepare($qry)
    {
        return new PDOVerticaStatement($this->conn, $qry);
    }

    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        $stmt = odbc_prepare($this->conn, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
        odbc_execute($stmt);
        $res = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);
        return $res['LAST_INSERT_ID'];
    }
}

class PDOVerticaStatement
{
    protected $qry;
    protected $param;
    protected $stmt;

    public function __construct($conn, $qry)
    {
        $this->qry = preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^):[^\s:]++/um', '?', $qry);
        $this->param = null;

        $this->extractParam($qry);

        $this->stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $this->qry);
    }

    public function bindValue($param, $val)
    {
        $this->param[$param] = $val;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->param == null)
            odbc_execute($this->stmt);
        else
            odbc_execute($this->stmt, $this->param);

        $this->clearParam();
    }

    public function fetch($option)
    {
        return odbc_fetch_array($this->stmt);
    }

    protected function extractParam($qry)
    {
        $qryArray = explode(" ", $qry);
        $ind = 0;

        while(isset($qryArray[$ind]))
        {
            if(preg_match("/^:/", $qryArray[$ind]))
                $this->param[$qryArray[$ind]] = null;

            ++$ind;
        }
    }

    protected function clearParam()
    {
        $ind = 0;

        while(isset($this->param[$ind]))
        {
            $this->param[$ind] = null;
            ++$ind;
        }
    }
}
```

I was pleasantly surprised to find that this works without me having to rewrite hundreds of modules. I do need to rework some of the SQL since there are differences between MySQL and Vertica, but those are just minor touch ups.

Anyway, should anyone choose to use these classes, keep in mind I only implemented what I needed in terms of functionalities and they only work with queries using placeholders for parameters (:someParameter). Use them and modify them at your own discretion.

Thanks for anyone who helped me.